# Why is $_POST empty? Using variable $row as a input name using foreach

Tags: php, mysql

*Hey, I have been trying to fix this for hours now. I'm fairly new to PHP, so have some sympathy for me!*

**I'm trying to call the $_POST[$id], and put it into a table using foreach. It's also telling me that id is an unidentified index. Any idea why? If you have any other pointers for a beginner,feel free to share**

Thank you in advance!

index form:

```
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $food = $row["food"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $picture = $row["picture"];
            $description = $row["description"];
            $id = $row['id'];

            echo "<tr>
                    <td><img src='$picture' width='120px' /></td>
                    <td>$food</td>
                    <td>$$price</td>
                    <td><input type='number' min='0' max='10' enctype='multipart/form-data' placeholder='#' name='<?php echo $id; ?>' maxlength='1'></td>
                </tr>";
        }
```

submitorder.php table:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $food = $row["food"];
            $price = $row["price"];

            $id = $_POST[$id];
            if(!empty($_POST[$id])){
                if(isset($_POST[$id])){
                    $qty = $_POST[$id];
                }else{
                    echo "Is NOT SET";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Is EMPTY";
            }

            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$food</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>$$price</td>
                </tr>";
        }
```

Comment: `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: ^-- `+1` ... and just not quite sure about the 2x `$` in `<td>$$price</td>` but that could be valid.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The $$price is so it echoes a $ in front of the price

Comment: OK. And does it actually echo it, or is there an error?

Comment: @zerkms  It's now saying that id is an unidentified index. Any idea why? Thanks again!

Comment: @jdish123 The first comment probably refers to this line: `$id = $_POST[$id];`

Comment: <input type='number' min='0' max='10' enctype='multipart/form-data' placeholder='#' name='<?php echo $id; ?>' maxlength='1'> has to be <input type='number' min='0' max='10' enctype='multipart/form-data' placeholder='#' name='qty' maxlength='1'> or something else

Comment: Try putting your `$id = $_POST[$id];` above your `while` loop

Comment: @jdish123 I'd still go for something like `<td>$'. $price .'</td>`

Comment: That's what I thought as well. PHP treats `$$` in a special manner @Marcel

Comment: And $qty = $_POST[$id]; => $qty = $_POST['qty'];

Comment: or `<td>${$price}</td>`

Comment: But i am not sure what you want to achieve with your ids everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $food = $row["food"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $picture = $row["picture"];
            $description = $row["description"];
            $id = $row['id'];

            echo '<tr>
                    <td><img src='.$picture.' width=\'120px\' /></td>
                    <td>'.$food.'</td>
                    <td>'.$price.'</td>
                    <td><input type=\'number\' min=\'0\' max=\'10\' enctype=\'multipart/form-data\' placeholder=\'#\' name='.$id.' maxlength=\'1\'></td>
                </tr>';
        }



while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $food = $row["food"];
                $price = $row["price"];
                   if(isset($_POST['id'])){
                        $qty = $_POST['id'];
                    }else{
                        echo "Is NOT SET";
                    }
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>' . $food . '</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>' .$price. '</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
```

fixed errors, the only other thing I could think of is that your form isn't actually using POST as the method. Also, for the sake of yourself and others, if the $_POST['id'] value is actually quantity, rename it to quantity to save yourself some headache.

Comment: And rename name='<?php echo $id; ?>' to name='qty'

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, missed it myself, it's updated now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<td><input type='number' min='0' max='10' enctype='multipart/form-data' placeholder='#' name='<?php echo $id; ?>' maxlength='1'></td>
```

Specifically, here:

```
.... name='<?php echo $id; ?>' ....
```

You are already in a PHP string. You should be concatenating instead. Otherwise, your element's name is literally `<?php echo [whatever the ID is]; ?>`